# Replacing last char (string) using regex or DOMDocument

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I'm using one small script to convert from absolute links to relative ones. It is working but it needs improvement. Not sure how to proceed. Please have a look at part of the script used for this.

Script:

```
public function links($path) {

    $old_url = 'http://test.dev/'; 

    $dir_handle = opendir($path);
    while($item = readdir($dir_handle)) {
        $new_path = $path."/".$item;
        if(is_dir($new_path) && $item != '.' && $item != '..') {
            $this->links($new_path);
        }
        // it is a file
        else{

            if($item != '.' && $item != '..')
            {
                $new_url = '';
                $depth_count = 1;
                $folder_depth = substr_count($new_path, '/');
                while($depth_count < $folder_depth){
                    $new_url .= '../';
                    $depth_count++;


                }

                $file_contents = file_get_contents($new_path);

                $doc = new DOMDocument;
                @$doc->loadHTML($file_contents);

                foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
                        if (substr($link, -1) == "/"){
                            $link->setAttribute('href', $link->getAttribute('href').'/index.html');
                        }

                    }

                $doc->saveHTML();
                $file_contents = str_replace($old_url,$new_url,$file_contents);
                file_put_contents($new_path,$file_contents);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I've added inside `while loop` that `DOMDocument` but it doesn't work. What I'm trying to achieve here is to add for every link at the end index.html if last char in that link is /

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong but where does the `$html` come from you're trying to load? It is not within your loop or function.

Comment: You were right, I've edited code but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents($new_path);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($file_contents);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query("//a");

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (substr($href, -1) === '/') {
        $link->setAttribute('href', $href."index.html");
    }
}

$new_file_content = $dom->saveHTML();
# save this wherever you want
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/7Ki0Or).

---

*Hint:* Your call to `$dom->saveHTML()` leads to nowhere (ie there's no variable capturing the output).

Comment: I see in demo that it is working but when I try this I get empty files... index.html or any other files (contact.html, about.html) are all empty now... Something isn't good... When I do echo $new_path it is showing just /index, /about/, /contact/ any other suggestions?

Comment: @Morpheus: Just use `file_put_contens("filename_here", $dom->saveHTML())` instead of messing around with your stuff :)